# Accessing multiple PHP pages through array

Tags: php

I need some help with this PHP pages.
I don't understand

```
session_start(); 
require("config/db.php"); 
if(isset($_GET['page'])){ 

    $pages=array("menu","cart"); 

    if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) { 

        $_page=$_GET['page']; 

    }else{ 

        $_page="menu"; 

    } 

}else{ 

    $_page="menu"; 

} 
?>
```

My code at the bottom calls $_page and it will display that PHP page,
in this case, menu.php. How do I make it call menu2.php if I were to select an option that changes the value to menu2?

EDIT:

Thanks for all your comments! I would like to add on that this is just a container in the website, and my output will be derived from

Comment: just try: header('Location:'.$_page); it will redirect to selected page

Comment: Are you asking how to redirect the user to another page?  Or something else?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: i have a container for the menu, "<?php require($_page.".php"); ?> " this outputs the current page that the user selected, for instance menu/menu1

Comment: Firstly, How do you intend to change the option, when you say "select an option" are you referring to a dropdown menu ie <select><option></option></select>?

Comment: @cookies im doing this via a list, but yes, that works too

Comment: So if I understand you well. <select><option value="menu.php">Menu</option><option value="menu2.php">Menu2</option></select>, and on selection one of the options it immediately changes the page right?

Comment: @cookies yes, correct. however it the new page has to be within the the mainbody div, rather than just a redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the sample code i created below, this should give you an idea, I hope.

```
<section href="#" id="showItem"></section>
<select id="options">
    <option value="page1.php">Page 1</option>
    <option value="page2.php">Page 2</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = $('select#options').val();
    var section = $('section#showItem');

    var getPage = function (url) {
        $.get(url).success(function (data) {
            section.html(data);
        }).error(function () {
            section.html("error loading page");
        });
    };

    $('select#options').change(function () {
        var options = $('select#options').val();
        getPage(options);
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        getPage(options);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i understand your code, but however i dont think it would be able to be applied to my case, are you able to add me on skype, i have a working webserver with the website to illustrate further haha

Comment: mikkytrionze101 add me up and drop me an email, so that i could know when you are on.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
header("Location:" . $_page . ".php");
```

where location can be any valid url/page name on the server relative to the current document.

Comment: Hi, i appreciate your answer! but i would like to ask, how do you get it to update in that specific page, as i have one index.php with all the code, is it possible to traverse the array and display a different page within the index itself? im using <?php require($_page.".php"); ?> to output it within the index

Answer (score -1):

just try: `header('Location:'.$_page.'.php');` it will redirect to selected page

Comment: Hi, i appreciate your answer! but i would like to ask, how do you get it to update in that specific page, as i have one index.php with all the code, is it possible to traverse the array and display a different page within the index itself? im using <?php require($_page.".php"); ?>  to output it within the index

Comment: yes you can include multiple files in one php file